# Tcl String function that does "shimmering" ruined my customized tcl type defined in c

Tags: c, tcl

I have defined a customized tcl type using tcl library in c/c++. I basically make the `Tcl_Obj.internalRep.otherValuePtr` point to my own data structure. The problem happens by calling `[string length myVar]` or other similar string functions that does so called shimmering behaviour which replace my internalRep with it's own string structure. So that after the string series tcl function, myVar cannot convert back! because it's a complicate data structure cannot be converted back from the `Tcl_Obj.bytes` representation plus the type is no longer my customized type. How can I avoid that.

Comment: Why are you doing things like `[string length myVar]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `string length` command converts the internal representation of the values it is given to the special `string`  type, which records information to allow many string operations to be performed rapidly. Apart from most of the `string` command's various subcommands, the `regexp` and `regsub` commands are the main ones that do this (for their string-to-match-the-RE-against argument). If you have a precious internal representation of your own and do not wish to lose it, you should avoid those commands; there are some operations that avoid the trouble. (Tcl mostly assumes that internal representations are *not* fragility, and therefore that they  can be regenerated on demand. Beware when using fragility!)

The key operations that are mostly safe (as in they generate the `bytes`/`length` rep through calling the `updateStringProc` if needed,  but don't clear the internal rep) are:

- substitution into a string; the substituted value won't have the internal rep, but it will still be in the original object.
- comparison with the `eq` and `ne` expression operators. This is particularly relevant for checks to see if the value is the empty string.

Be aware that there are many other operations that spoil the internal representation in other ways, but most don't catch people out so much.

---

[EDIT — far too long for a comment]: There are a number of relatively well-known extensions that work this way (e.g., TCOM and Tcl/Java both do this). The only thing you can really do is “be careful” as the values really are fragile. For example, put them in an array and then pass the indexes into the array around instead, as those need not be fragile. Or keep things as elements in a list (probably in a global variable) and pass around the list indices; those are just plain old numbers.

The traditional, robust approach is to put a map (e.g., a `Tcl_HashTable` or `std::map`) in your C or C++ code and have the indices into that be short strings with not too much meaning (I like to use the name of the type of value followed by either a sequence number or a serialisation of the pointer, such as you might get with the `%p` conversion in `sprintf()`; the printed pointer reveals more of the implementation details, is a little more helpful if you're debugging, and generally doesn't actually make that much difference in practice). You then have the removal of things from the map be an explicit deletion operation, and it is also easy to provide operations like listing all the known current values. This is safe, but prone to “leaking” (though it's not *formally* a memory leak if you provide the listing operation). It can be accelerated by *caching the lookup* in a `Tcl_Obj*`'s internal representation (a cheap way to handle deletion is to use a sequence number that you increment when you delete something, and only bypass the map lookup if the sequence number that you cache in the intrep is equal to the main sequence number) but it's not usually a big deal; only go to that sort of thing if you've measured a bottleneck in the lookups.

But I'd probably just live with fragility in my own code, and would just take care to ensure that I never bust the assumptions. The problem is really that you're being incautious about how you use the values; the Tcl code should *just pass them around* and nothing else really. Also, I've experimented a fair bit with wrapping such things up inside a TclOO object; it's far too heavyweight (by the design of TclOO) for values that you're making a lot of, but if you've only got a few of them and you're wanting to treat them as objects with methods, this can work very well indeed (and gives many more options for automatic cleanup).

Comment: Donal's answer certainly tells you what to avoid in your attempts to preserve your internal type's representation, but from my reading of your question you seem to have an internal representation that cannot be constructed from a string. I can sympathize that the code to generate complex internal types from a string can be difficult to write (having written several myself), but I fear that without a well formed string representation for your custom type, you are leaving little land mines for some script to stubble over that will be very difficult to diagnose from the script level.

Comment: @andymango Was going to comment on that, but it was FAR to long for even a series of comments so I added to my answer. 

Comment: @DonalFellows do you know how can I output some message to the console in the Tcl_freeInternalrepProc function? I tried `Tcl_Eval(interp, "puts warning")` but not working as it will give run-time error: "TclStackFree: incorrect freePtr (0x7f3c71559e20 != 0x7f3c71559e0f). Call out of sequence?"